# Why does System.Threading.Timer stop on its own?

Tags: c#, .net, service, timer

I'm doing a small test project before I use `System.Threading.Timer` in a Windows Service project. It's working wonderfully, however the timer stops on its own after a minute or two.

The full source for the test project is:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace studyTimers {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(tick);
            System.Threading.Timer testTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, 1000, 1000);
        }

        void tick(Object obj) {
            if (label1.InvokeRequired) {
                label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => tick(obj)));
            } else {
                label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is obviously to update a label with the current time. I am noticing that updating stops after a bit. Why would this be?

Comment: @Michael Burr
: why did you overwrite my edit, making the code hidden again?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you need a timer on a Windows Form then drop a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` onto the form - there's no reason to use a `System.Threading.Timer` unless you need better resolution than 55 ms.

The reason the timer "stops" is because it's being garbage-collected.  You're allowing it to go out of scope in the `Form1_Load` method because you only declare it as a local variable.  In order to keep the timer "alive", it needs to be a private field on the form class so that the GC knows it's still needed.

In other words:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.Threading.Timer testTimer;

    ...

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(tick);
        testTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

But again, in this case it's simplier to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which is an actual component in the toolbox that you can just drop onto the form.

---

*Edit* - As the comments now reveal, if this is just a test app and the real application is in a Windows Service, you *cannot* use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` for that.  Just remember not to let your `System.Threading.Timer` go out of scope.

Comment: That's actually what the timer in the service is using, and it isn't firing. This is just a small test project.

Answer (score 4):

Garbage collector collected the timer object, you should keep a reference to it.
this post will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: There is already an answer that contains this information.  Repeating it but in far less detail is not helpful.