# C# Timer getting stopped after some time

Tags: c#

I am using this code for a C# service, "SomeFuction" should run after every 6 minutes, but after some 30 minutes its getting stopped.

What I'm missing here? I want it to run till my service is running, please help :(

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            try
            { SomeFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3); }
            catch
            { return;}

        }, null, 0, 360000);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that the `Timer` gets disposed by the `GarbageCollector`? It seems like you only declare the **variable** holding the Timer-Reference in a **local scope**.

To prevent GarbageCollection, make sure that the Timer-Reference gets stored in an Object that exists for the entire lifetime of the Service.

See this post for a similar issue: [Why does System.Threading.Timer stop on its own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196825/why-does-system-threading-timer-stop-on-its-own)

Comment: Thanks Manuel for quick response, I have changed that variable to private. Now i need to wait for some hours to see if it works. :(
Thanks for your help bud! Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

What's the rest of the code look like? Is the Timer object going out of scope?

Comment: This is not an answer should be a comment